# Modelio menu doesn't show up after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: menu, ubuntu-13.10, modelio

[image: modelio menu doesn't show up]

Modelio top bar menu doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.10 .
Only stubs appear when clicking on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

- open terminal
- sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/modelio.desktop
- type the path to the application between brackets. Exec is the command that should be launched from the terminal

`[Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=Modelio 3.1
    Icon=/[path to the application]/Modelio\ 3.1/icon
    Comment=Modelio UML flowchart editor
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /[path to the application]/Modelio\ 3.1/modelio
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    Categories=Development;UML;`

- save

based on [menu doesn't show on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show/)